# XMLHttpRequest strips trailing whitespace from URL before encoding

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, url-encoding

In Windows Chrome 38 (and maybe other browsers), XMLHttpRequest seems to automatically encode URLs, *but it strips trailing spaces first*:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', 'http://example.com/a?b= c d '); // note three spaces
x.send();
```

Running that code in the console gives:

> GET http://example.com/a?b=%20c%20d 404 (Not Found)

The trailing space has been stripped, *then* the URL was encoded.

1. **Where is this behaviour documented?**

I want it to encode the trailing space *without* stripping it.

2. **Should I be encoding the URL myself before calling XHR.open()?**

Comment: You should probably be encoding the URL yourself since what you give to the XMLHttpRequest should be a legal URL and spaces are not a legal character in the URL.

Comment: `%20` is an encoded space. Have you tried `?b=%20c%20d%20`

Comment: In a real application I would encode it myself, but I still wonder why the XMLHttpRequest seems to be encoding the URL. I guess it's just doing the same thing that the browser does when you type spaces into the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

> Where is this behaviour documented?

The [`XHR`'s `open` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method) parses its URL argument with the [basic url parser](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-basic-url-parser), which - in its first step - strips leading and trailing whitespaces from its input.

> Should I be encoding the URL myself before calling XHR.open()?

Yes. Just use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) on it:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', encodeURI('http://example.com/a?b= c d '));
x.send();
```

But also consider to get rid of this invalid url string right from the beginning, i.e. before the string is constructed. I'm not sure where you are getting the parameter value from, but it could look like

```
x.open('GET', 'http://example.com/a?b='+encodeURIComponent(…));
```

Comment: So you've told me where the first part (trimming) is documented, but not the second (encoding). Is this documented or is it Postel's Law in action?

Comment: BTW the parameter comes from user input (typing ` c d ` into an input field). encodeURIComponent() is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I can't find it in the spec. XHR deals only with the URL object that is obtained by parsing, and passes it (in the `send` method) to the [*fetch* algorithm](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#fetch). The URL object constructed for the referrer is explicitly serialised there, but for the actual ressource URL I can only find "*When a URL is to be fetched, the URL identifies a resource to be obtained*" and *"at a time convenient to the user and the user agent, download (or otherwise obtain) the resource, applying the semantics of the relevant specifications*".

Answer (score 0):

Under the section named "basic URL parser" in [this document](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#parsers), you can see a reference to removing leading and trailing whitespace.  That document is referenced by this [XMLHttpRequest document](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#refsURL) where is describes the url parameter of `open()`.

You can solve this issue by encoding the URL yourself before calling `open()` because the URL you give to `open()` should be a legal URL and spaces are not legal URL characters.  That encoding will also take care of the removal of leading and trailing whitespace (since there will be no whitespace any more).